# Lebesgue vs. Riemann integrable function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

While trying to learn the difference between Lebesgue and Riemann integrals, I came across the following example:
$$\int_{0}^{1}t^\lambda\,\mathrm dt$$
What I know so far:

- only for $\lambda>0$ the integral exists as a Riemann integral,
- only for $\lambda>1$ it exists as an improper Riemann integral.

My question is: for which $\lambda$'s does it exist as a Lebesgue integral?

(I suspect it's the same as with the improper case since $|t^\lambda|=t^\lambda$, or is there more to it?)

Comment: I presume you meant $\lambda > -1$ in the second? And yes, it exists as a Lebesgue integral for $\lambda >-1$. The catch with the Riemann integral for the $\lambda \in (-1,0)$ case is that the integrand is unbounded near zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\lambda > -1$, use Monotone Convergence Theorem on $t^\lambda \chi_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

For $\lambda \leq -1 $, assume that the integral is finite. Then it is finite for each $t^\lambda \chi_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}$. But this integral gets arbitrarily large as $n$ goes to infinity which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question: What exactly does it contradict to? We have been told that it contradicts the dominated convergence theorem but I don't quite see why.

Comment: @mathusiast I started with the assumption that the integral is finite, that is, the function is integrable for $\lambda \leq -1$. Since it is integrable, $t^\lambda \chi_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}$ is integrable and since the function is smaller than or equal to $t^{\lambda}$, the integral is at least not larger. But this becomes arbitrarily large. This contradicts the first assumption that was made, that the integral is finite.